# Weird Devise create user database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I find the following database connection quite weird:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 21:08:10 +0800
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RfHtAnEp8YkhMU=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Jason", "email"=>"bb@cc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'bb@cc.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('bb@cc.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-12-09 13:08:10.904314"], ["email", "bb@cc.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$ExmT7uQlTfda.zr0wQPvKdhdpn.SWV8C"], ["name", "Jason"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-09 13:08:10.904314"]]
   (8.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/index
Completed 302 Found in 98ms (ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)
```

The controller is a newly created one, not the default devise controller and I removed the :registrable module from the User model.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    redirect_to admin_index_path
  end
end
```

**Edit:** I've added the following validations:

```
 validates_presence_of :email
 validates :name, length: { in: 1..28}
 validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
```

I am just wondering why there were two "User Exists" connections before SQL INSERT? Is this normal?

Comment: Have you added validations to the User model manually?

Comment: Yes, I validated some, any ways to rectify this?

Comment: Devise adds its own validations to the model, so there will be two uniqueness validations for the email attribute, one case sensitive, one insensitive, hence the two queries in the log.